# Laravel whereRaw binding on operator

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

So I have a query where depending on what the user inputs, the column, operator and comparison can vary. For example, if the user chooses to filter the name column where it contains part of a string.

The problem arises when I try to bind the operator. Here is the query

```
$accounts->whereRaw("CASE WHEN 'adam' ? '%adam%' THEN name = 'adam' 
   WHEN 'adam' ? '%adam%' THEN name <> 'adam' ELSE name = 'bob' END", [
       'like',
       'not like',
]);
```

The error I'm getting is `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? '%adam%'`

If I hardcode `like` instead of `?`, it works, but I can't do that because the operator depends on the user input

EDIT: Had to edit this as I discovered the problem was different from the original problem, but similar.

Answer (score 0):

"When" must be followed by the condition, in this case, you need to replace 'adam'

```
CASE WHEN 'adam'
```